# Wordpress sorting function not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Well I am customizing this function a little but after multiple tries I am still getting to achieve the target actually this php code only show the oldest post first but I want to add a sort function in it so that it will show the latest posts which I am posting on daily basis first.
I even tried and added some function from wordpress codex but as I am not expert in php that’s why these technical thing are too much difficult for me. 
Help me in this code:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
if ( empty($image_width) ) {
if ( $columns == 1 )
$image_width = 960;
else
$image_width = 480;
}
if ( $image_ratio && $image_width ) {
$image_height = cloudfw_match_ratio( $image_width, $image_ratio );
}
$atts[ 'show_side_date_year' ] = false;
while( $posts->have_posts() ) :
$posts->the_post();
$post_data = $this->get_post();
/** Item number */
$i++;
$item_content = '';
$item_classes = array();
$item_classes[] = 'ui--blog-item ui--animation ui--accent-gradient-hover-parent clearfix';
$item_classes[] = 'layout--' . $raw_layout;
if ( $i == $post_count )
$item_classes[] = 'last-item';
$item_content .= "<div".
cloudfw_make_class( $item_classes, true ) .
">";
$link_element = array();
$link_element[0] = "<a class=\"ui--blog-link\" href=\"". $post_data['permalink'] ."\"";
$link_element[0] .= ">";
$link_element[1] = "</a>";
$item_content .= $this->side( $post_data, $atts );
$item_content .= "<div class=\"ui--blog-content-wrapper\">";
$item_content .= "<div class=\"ui--blog-header\">";
$item_content .= "<{$title_element} class=\"ui--blog-title\">" . $link_element[0] . $post_data['title'] . $link_element[1] . "</{$title_element}>";
$metas = $this->get_blog_metas( $metas_primary, $post_data );
$likes = $this->get_blog_metas( $metas_secondary, $post_data );
$item_content .= "</div>";
$excerpt = $this->get_excerpt( array('readmore' => $readmore, 'excerpt' => $show_excerpt, 'excerpt_length' => $excerpt_length, 'use_more_link' => false ) );
if ( !empty($excerpt)) {
$item_content .= "<div class=\"ui--blog-content\">";
$item_content .= $excerpt;
$item_content .= "</div>";
}
$item_content .= "<div class=\"ui--blog-readmore more-link\">";
$item_content .= "<a class=\"btn btn-small ". cloudfw_make_button_style( cloudfw_get_option( 'blog_template_mini', 'button_color', 'btn-secondary muted' ), true ) . "\" href=\"". $post_data['permalink'] ."\"";
$item_content .= ">";
$item_content .= $readmore;
$item_content .= "</a>";
$item_content .= "</div>";
$item_content .= "</div>";
$item_content .= "</div>";
if ( $columns > 1 ) {
$column_array = array();
$column_array['class'] = array();
$column_array['_key'] = 'blog_mini';
//$content_out .= $item_content;
$content_out .= cloudfw_UI_column( $column_array, $item_content, '1of' . $columns . ( $i % $columns == 0 ? '_last' : '' ), $i == $post_count );
} else {
$content_out .= $item_content;
}
endwhile;
```

Comment: Where are you calling `the_query()?`

Comment: No I am not using it anywhere

Comment: Don't you need to? Otherwise, what's going to be in `$posts`?

Comment: well if its possible to resolve the isssue by changing some little code then its ok, as I am don't know too much about PHP but I research on wordpress support and tried some $args etc and nothing works for me the only code which I have is mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

try to put below code above this statement: while( $posts->have_posts() ) :

```
$req_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$page_var =1;
$post_per_page = 10;
$page_var = $_GET['page'];
if(! $page_var)
{
    preg_match("/page\/(\d+)+/", $req_url, $matches);
    $page_var = $matches[1];
}
$args = array('post_type'=> 'post','orderby' => 'post_date','order' => 'DESC','post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' =>$post_per_page, 'paged'=>$page_var);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: THis should work. It means its getting overwrite from somewhere. (may be plugin or functions.php). What is your file name.. or do send complete source of your page or URL?

Comment: its actually a template i bought and yes I can send you the complete source files but not sure how? please update me how can i send you

Comment: you can paste file name and full source code here, plus which theme you are using?

Comment: I am using envision multi-purpose responsive theme

Comment: this theme is by wptation and causing error in mini blog template available on home page codes